# Flutter - include a zip file with an app and delete it at after processing (can I delete Assets at runtime?)

Tags: flutter

I want to include a zip file in my flutter app.  When the user runs the app for the first time, I will process that zip file (saving the contents using `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()` for example) and then I will want to delete the zip file...to save space on the user's machine.

Is it possible to delete an asset at runtime?

Or is there another way to achieve including a file in the installation and then deleting it at runtime?

Comment: Did you find a way to delete an assets-file ? (is this at all possible). If I understand your question correctly you would like to delete the assets-file (not the copied file in the ApplicationDocumentsDirectory). I would like to do exactly the same - i.e delete asset not appDocDir-file. Appreciate any comment !

Comment: Hi, I haven't yet looked at the problem again, I'll let you know if I find a way though!

Comment: @iKK Did you manage to find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is straightforward.
In your first widget which is run at startup you could detect if the file exists and then delete with :

```
File file = new File((await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path + "myfile.zip");
if (file.existsSync()) {
  file.delete();
}
```

Or you could use preferences to store a flag when it is deleted (and check the flag at startup).